# Read/Write legacy Thumbs.db?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-10, disassembly

For purpose of fast viewing my virtual network drive through `Dokany` library, I need ability to write/read `Thumbs.db` files.
As I see now `Thumbs.db` is just a serialization format for key/value images (like for example, key is a name of file, and value is a set of different size previews) and doesn't contain anything else.

Is there an easy way to serialize/deserialze those files?
For example, I can generate previews of different sizes in my cloud when I load new file into it and can serialize them on fly (or cache them myself) when `explorer.exe` wants to read `Thumbs.db`, but how to serialize them? Any library or sufficient serializer out there for `.NET50` ?

**Update 1**

Managed to extract files from `Thumbs.db` using this code and library from nuget `OpenMcdf`:

```
        var cf = new CompoundFile(filePath);
        if (Directory.Exists(outputFolder))
            Directory.Delete(outputFolder, true);
        cf.RootStorage.VisitEntries(x =>
        {
            if (x.IsStream)
            {
                var stream = (CFStream)x;
                var data = stream.GetData();
                var offset = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
                var someInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);//type?
                var imageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);
                var someInt3 = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 12);//???
                var jpgData = data.AsSpan(offset).ToArray();
                var headerData = data.AsSpan(0, offset).ToArray();

                Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(outputFolder, x.Name + ".jpeg"), jpgData);
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(outputFolder, x.Name + ".bin"), headerData);
            }
        }, true);
```

But now facing an issue - `x.Name` is a hash of original file name in folder, so I need somehow to obtain this hash function to create my own Thumbs.db. Any thoughs? Someone proficient in disassembling can help?
It is probably contained in `thumbcache.dll` in windows folder, but Im not profficient in disassembling to extract this function.

Comment: `Thumbs.db` is a *OLE Compound File format*, and I have seen a library for this floating around the intwebs in my travels. Also there should be duplicates here somewhere

Comment: Wow! Already tried to parse with one of nuget libraries, and see some results. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @TheGeneral I managed to get entries out of this, but unable to interpret stream data. Any help?

Comment: Unfortunately its nothing I have tried before.

Comment: Managed to extract files, but now Im facing new issue - can't generate file hash. Windows probably uses it to identify file in Thumbs.db, and it correlates with original file name. I.e filename -> filehash -> search for filehash in Thumbs.db

Comment: I think you have enough for a self answer, maybe this now is another question

Comment: Well, still can't write Thumbs.db, this is a part of the question. If only I had this hashing algo, I can recreate Thumbs.db creation.